# AWSAppSyncClient does not detect graphql queries

Tags: android, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

[image]I am using AWS `AppSync` in my Android application and following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-android-app-with-aws-amplify-part-1/) link but I have already created API in my AppSync which I wish to import in my Android app. I am linking the app using `Amplify`.

Comment: have you tried using ctrl+space buttons.

Comment: of course! now, I am this another error.

Comment: You mentioned that you downloaded the schema. This should have been done by the Amplify CLI. Just verifying that you didn't manually move something.

Comment: @donkon You're correct. I did repeat the process and it was autogenerate, but now I'm facing this another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.So turns out that the queries in `AppSync` were created by a developer who was not familiar with naming conventions, he put "_" (*underscore*) in the queries and when those queries are processed by `Amplify`, it removes all the _ only from `type`, `mutation` and `query` names but, not from the methods inside them. For example,

```
type Query {
  getDaily_Build(id: ID!): Daily_Build
}
```

in the AppSync generates following query in `queries.graphql` in Android

```
query GetDailyBuild($id: ID!) {
  getDaily_Build(id: $id) {
    id
    username
    title
  }
}
```

and this gave the error

> Validation of GraphQL query document failed.

I changed the schema following the naming conventions and avoided use of special characters like "_" and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Underscore handling is a known issue at least in the iOS AppSync SDK: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios/issues/137  Because that issue describes an interaction with the code generation side, it may also affect Android.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I was not aware of it on the iOS side until you mentioned, hope this helps to iOS developers as well then :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured all required plugins and libraries in gradle file..

```
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'

implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.6.+'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
```

and in manifest you need to have the following permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and you need to have the following service in your application tag.

```
 <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />
```

Comment: yes. I have also added these libraries
    `implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true}`
    `implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true }`
    `implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true }`
and 

`implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.9.2'`